# Within subjects main effect in an ANOVA changes after a between subjects variable is included in the model

Tags: spss, anova

Yesterday my colleagues (all researchers) and I were bewildered by something. My colleague was asked to revise her article by the reviewers of a journal. She had done 3 repeated measures ANOVAs  to answer each of the research questions, and the reviewers asked her to check for differences in the between subjects measure (in this case gender). She therefore set out to repeat her ANOVA (in SPSS) as a mixed model, with the repeated measures staying the same, but adding one between subjects measure (gender). She found no significant differences in gender and one significant interaction of a within subjects measure and gender (not problematic for this paper).

*Here is the baffling part though:* Her main within-subjects effects suddenly had changed - different F and p values were shown.

This defies my knowledge and understanding of what a mixed model ANOVA calculates. As I understand it:

**F(within subjects main effect) = MS(within) / MS error(within)**

F(within subjects * between subjects interaction) = MS(within * between) / MS error(within)

F(between subjects main effect) = MS(between) / MS error(between)

The **F value of the within subjects main effect** should not change, whether you are including a between subjects variable or not. This calculation is based on the same numbers either way and should therefore yield the same results either way. What are we missing here? What are we not understanding?

Comment: I'm not an expert for repeated linear models, but I would guess your degrees of freedom for SS error get lowered by 2, because of new parameters in model ([repeats-1]*[genders-1]=2).

. But it's just my tip...

Comment: interesting. thanks for the tip! I will look into that. meanwhile, any other answers are much appreciated!